# Weakening compactness in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is the following true in a general metric space $X$?

Every net (in $X$) of cardinality $\kappa$ contains a convergent subnet of cardinality $\kappa$ if and only if every open cover of $X$ admits a subcover of cardinality $<\kappa$, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$.

If not, can the statement be somehow modified so as to obtain an equivalence? It seems to me that something along these lines should hold true in general.

Comment: Since metric spaces are first-countable, I think that you can probably reduce this back to sequences again. Or at least countable nets.

Comment: There are three different notions of *subnet* in fairly common use, so you really need to specify which definition you’re using.

Comment: Does one of the three definitions make the above statement true?

Comment: What is "the cardinaility of a net"? That of its domain or its image?